# unit testing with generated protobuf code in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a general question regarding unit testing with generated code.  So I have a method like:

```
public Proto.MyResponse generateCert(String id) throws Exception {
      Proto.MyResponse.Builder builder = Proto.MyResponse.newBuilder();

      // do some logic and set properties on the builder like
      builder.setResponse(SUCCESS);

      return builder.build();
}
```

So if I try to unit test this method, it'll fail right away with a NPE.  Do I need to put the builder logic into some other class that implements that this class injects so I can mock out the call to create the builder?  Just curious if that is the best approach since I can imagine that I will have to build out various messages and have logic similar to this where within a method I

1) do logic 
2) set properties on builder based on (1)
3) return the built message

Comment: Where is this NPE thrown?

Comment: @JoeC On the first line with Proto.MyResponse

Comment: My question is: why doesn't the caller use the builder itself? Why do you need this boiler plate  code? And on topic: avoid *static access*! Pass in the builder instance via *dependency injection*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle the builder is generated code. It basically does logic and sets properties in the builder.

Comment: @Crystal If it is generated, why would you test it? if you don't trust your generator framework, why are you using it?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm trying to test the method that uses the generated code. Just didn't know what the best way to do it was

Comment: @Crystal *"I'm trying to test the method that **uses** the generated code"*  - Is that the code you posted? Then apply DI instead of statically accessing the builder instance.